# unable to create Db2 service on IBM Free Account

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Ive just started with IBM Cloud and am trying to do a Db2 setup from the catalog on my academic free account.

Been hitting [500, Internal Service error] forever now. I've attached the screenshot. Can someone help and advise what are the next steps pls? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjkXN.png)

Comment: I don't have any anwer, but I guess you'd better add ibm-cloud tag to get one.

Comment: Have you tried contacting IBM support?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be addressed to the vendor support.